# Trying have more text slide out with translateX, my function is only responding to one event trigger

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to have one of my `<h4>` tags slide when you hover one of my `<h2>` tags, based off of the event trigger. That would give the hover over text tag and add more text effect. Both `<h2>` are siblings to my `<h4>` tags.

With `nextElementSibling` I can only `translateX` one `<h4>` tag. With another method like `children` I move both with `translateX` at the same time. But I would like to only move one, corresponding to the event trigger.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var subHeader = document.querySelector('.slideText');
    // This supposed to grab more than one <h4>
    subHeader.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        //.slideText is set to two different <h4>'s'
        $(event.target.nextElementSibling).css({
          'transform': 'translateX( 65px )',
          'transition': 'transform 0.75s'
        });
    });
}




 <div className="firstRowImg-overlay">
            <h2 className='slideText'>
             Live retro shop
            </h2>
            <h4>
              Always Good Vibes
            </h4>
            </div>
        </div>

          <div className="firstRowImg-overlay">
            <h2 className="slideText">
              Home Made, Southern Style
            </h2>
            <h4>
              The Whole Towns Sweet Tooth
            </h4>
          </div>
```

Comment: @Claies Yeah, I didn't mean to post it so soon I was editing as fast as I could. I might have to just delete it and try again.  . sigh SO.. :I

Comment: the first problem here is that `document.querySelector` only returns the **first** element with the selector.  you *probably* will want to use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead, which returns a list of elements, then iterate through the list to add the event for each element.

Comment: @Claies Thanks big time I completely forgot that, worrying about other problems I've made.lol But from here I would just access the desired elements through an array and addEventListeners through them.